# How can I provide proof of residency

Tags: united-states, privacy, minor

So I am moving to another state (pooler, Ga.) and I need to enroll
My son into school. I would need to provide proof of residency
But I will be staying with my mother in law until I get more familiar 
With the city and find myself and my children a home of our own. What can I do to provide proof of where I’m living ?

Comment: Proof of residency for school enrollment? Probably best to ask the school what they require.

Answer (score 1):

The [school district says](http://internet.savannah.chatham.k12.ga.us/district/AcademicAffairs/PupilPersonnel/StudentRegistration/Pages/RegistrationInfoandRequirements.aspx) you need to supply the following documents:

```
    Birth Certificate (certified copy)
    Georgia Certificate of Immunization – Form 3231
    Georgia Ear, Eye, and Dental Certificate (EED)
    Proof of Address (one of the following items listed below)
        current mortgage statement
        current lease or rental agreement (month to month)
        current gas, electric, or water bill
        current governmental agency mail (county, state, or federal)
```

The US department of Justice also has [something to say](https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/crt/legacy/2014/05/08/plylerfact.pdf) about this. For example, they "*may not* prevent or discourage your child from enrolling in or attending school because he or 
she lacks a birth certificate". Proof of residency can be challenging, for example you need two forms of proof for a drivers license transfer. A bank statement and library card may satisfy DMV.

Under the federal McKinney-Vento Homeless Assistance Act, you may qualify as technically "homeless", and homeless children cannot be required to show proof of residency. The Dept. of Education provides [this information](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/docs/qa-201101.pdf); it is unlikely that they will deny a student the right to enroll because of inadequate documentation.